# FormClosing event when application closed from task manager

Tags: c#, winforms

In my Winforms application, I show a `MessageBox` when the user closes the application to prompt him or her to save data. When the application is closed via the Task Manager, this dialog should not appear, as the closing of the application should be forced through no matter what. However, I am encountering a problem where my warning dialog will flash on the screen before the application is closed by the Task Manager. I have tried checking `e.CloseReason` in my `FormClosingEventHandler`, but to no avail. I even made a simple project to demonstrate the issue (this is literally the only code that I have in it).

```
    private void Form1_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CloseReason)
        {
            case CloseReason.UserClosing:
                MessageBox.Show("User");
                break;
            case CloseReason.TaskManagerClosing:
                MessageBox.Show("Task Manager");
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Other");
                break;
        }
    }
```

When I kill this application via Task Manager > End Task, the "User" message pops up, not "Task Manager"! I have seen plenty of posts about handling this event; however, none of them seem to solve my problem.

Note: I am using .Net version 4.6.01586 and Windows 10.

Comment: Seems to be the new behavior since Windows 8.1

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Thanks for finding that, I didn't see it while searching :)